# Confidence intervals for generalized linear model from `lmList`

Tags: r, lme4

I'm trying to compute confidence intervals for groups with a common model using `lmList` from the `lme4` package. It works fine for normal linear model, but fails when the dependent variable is dichotomous. For example, this works fine:

```
d <- data.frame(
  g = sample(c("A","B","C","D","E"), 250, replace=TRUE),
  y1 = runif(250, max=100),
  y2 = sample(c(0,1), 250, replace=TRUE)
)

library(lme4)

fm1 <- lmList(y1 ~ 1 | g, data=d)
```

I can extract the coefficients using `coef(fm1)` and the confidence interval for the coefficients using `confint(fm1)`. Then I run a model with the dichotomous outcome:

```
fm2 <- lmList(y2 ~ 1 | g, data=d, family=binomial)
```

I can still get the coefficients using `coef(fm2)`, but when I try to get the confidence intervals, I get an error:

```
> confint(fm2)
Waiting for profiling to be done...
Waiting for profiling to be done...
Error in val[, , i] <- eval(mCall) : incorrect number of subscripts
```

I was originally going to post this to stats.stackexchange because I thought it might be something I don't understand about the confidence intervals of GLMs, but then I figured out that I can still get the confidence intervals using

```
by(d, d$g, function(x) confint(glm(y2 ~ 1, data=x, family=binomial)))
```

Is there some way to do this using `lmList`?

```
> sessionInfo()
R version 2.15.0 (2012-03-30)
Platform: x86_64-pc-mingw32/x64 (64-bit)

locale:
[1] LC_COLLATE=German_Germany.1252  LC_CTYPE=German_Germany.1252  
[3] LC_MONETARY=German_Germany.1252 LC_NUMERIC=C                  
[5] LC_TIME=German_Germany.1252   

attached base packages:
[1] stats     graphics  grDevices utils     datasets  methods   base    

other attached packages:
[1] lme4_0.999375-42 Matrix_1.0-6     lattice_0.20-6 

loaded via a namespace (and not attached):
[1] grid_2.15.0   MASS_7.3-17   nlme_3.1-103  stats4_2.15.0 tools_2.15.0
```

Comment: I think this is a bug in the "!missing(family)" branch of lmList, or its processing by confint.lmList. Note that when you try "family=gaussian", it also produces the error in confint. There is nothing wrong in using by() or ddply in this case.

Comment: Ah ha, ok. Nice catch. I'll just go with the `by()` method then. Thanks for the comment.

Comment: @BenBolker Should we file a bug report on this minor issue, or let Douglas focus on more important things such?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is indeed a bug, I'm working on a fix. It turns out to be fairly straightforward: the basic problem is that `confint.lm` returns a matrix while `confint.glm` returns a data frame.

In general I **strongly** recommend posting all but the most trivial bug fixes to the bug tracker at http://r-forge.r-project.org/tracker/?atid=298&group_id=60&func=browse (I complain about R-core's attitude toward bug reports, so for consistency I have to follow my own rules ...) Thanks for the report!

Comment: Thanks! To be honest, I assumed it was something I was doing wrong or missing and so I didn't think to file a bug report.

Comment: Let me clarify a bit: I mean that, once you're pretty sure something is a bug (e.g. after asking on r-help or stack overflow to clarify if you're not sure), you should file a bug report.  Asking for clarification when you're not sure is a great idea.  (This part of my answer was mostly responding to @Dieter Menne's comment.)